# how to pass dynamic variable inside function to another function inside it?

Tags: javascript, validation, variables

How to pass dynamic variable inside function  to another function inside it

i am trying to set dynamic clearing function and i am having issue with this code

```
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
var email = document.getElementById('Email');

    function Clear(Vars) {
        for (i = 0; i < Vars.length; i++) {
           Vars[i].addEventListener("click", Clr, false);
           Vars[i].addEventListener("oninput", Clr, false);
          }
            function Clr(){
               Vars[i].setCustomValidity('');
               Vars[i].style.removeProperty('border');
            }

     };

Clear([email, firstName, lastName]);
```

trying to find an easy way to pass "Vars[i]" to the second function.

Comment: Your issue is with `i`, not `Vars`. Can't you just use `this`?

Comment: ohh i see that now , any idea how to pass the "i" to 2nd function without typing for loop again ? also i am trying to avoid "this" for now 
THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function Clr(){
         this.setCustomValidity('');
         this.style.removeProperty('border');
 }
```

either use this, or use *let* :

```
 for (let i = 0; i < Vars.length; i++) {
      function Clr(){
           Vars[i].setCustomValidity('');
           Vars[i].style.removeProperty('border');
        }

       Vars[i].addEventListener("click", Clr, false);
       Vars[i].addEventListener("oninput", Clr, false);
 }
```

Comment: i am trying to avoid "this" at the moment and the second option Vars came undefined

Comment: @RaadAltaie cause you probably forgot the let

Comment: i added "function Clear(Vars) { " line , its working now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you sure your code work correctly?
When `for` loop is end, `i` value is `Vars.length`. So in `Clr` function, `Vars[i]` should be undefined.
Following code may be helpful for you:

```js
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
var email = document.getElementById('Email');

  function Clear(Vars) {
      for (i = 0; i < Vars.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
          Vars[i].addEventListener("click", Clr, false);
          Vars[i].addEventListener("oninput", Clr, false);
          function Clr(){
             Vars[i].setCustomValidity('');
             Vars[i].style.removeProperty('border');
          }
         })(i);
       }
   };

Clear([email, firstName, lastName]);
```